# Darboux reference for a regular parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

I want to determine the Darboux reference for a given regular parametrization. I know the matricial expression for the natural parametrization but i was wondering whether, as it happens with Frenets reference, there was a proportionality constnat between the expression for a given parametrization and the natural one.

I've tried to determine this constant and, for the relationship of $t'=k_n N +  k_g S$ I've got that, same as in frenet, for a given parametrization $t' = ||\gamma '(t)|| [k_n N ×+ k_g S]$.

However, I've tried to check whether this constant factor holds for all three of the derivatives of the frenet reference but I cant get it.

I'd apreciate if anyone could help me check if the factor holds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Frenet formulas hold for an arclength (i.e., speed $1$) parametrization. Your second formula comes from $df/dt = (df/ds)(ds/dt)$, since $\|\gamma’(t)\| = ds/dt$.